# ViewModel and access shape in ControlTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a button.I need to access a shape in Template.But I can't get it to work for me.
My Template:

```
<Grid x:Name="root">
 <Ellipse x:Name="border" Width="50" Height="50" Fill="Azure"/>
 <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
</Grid>
```

ViewModel

```
public ICommand CmdAction {
 get {
  cmdAction = cmdAction ?? new RelayCommand(x => Action(), x => true);
  return cmAction;
 }
}

void Action()
{
     Storyboard board = Application.Current.FindResource("Storyborder") as Storyboard;
     var shapeborder = Application.Current.FindResource("border") as Ellipse;
     if (!mode) {
      shapeborder.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
      board.Begin(shapeborder, true);
      mode = true;
     } else {
      mode = false;
      board.Stop(shapeborder);
      shapeborder.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
     }
}
```

I tried:

```
var btn=((Window1)Application.Current.MainWindow).bt;
Grid grid = btn.Template.FindName("root",btn) as Grid;
var lb = grid.FindName("border") as Ellipse;
```

Comment: From your question it's hard to tell what you are trying to achieve actually. Just a guess, but it may make sense to add a boolean property to your view model that is toggled by the command action, and have a DataTrigger on that property in your ControlTemplate to control element visibility and animations.

Comment: Do you want to change your template in runtime?

Comment: I want to set shape property in Template @ClayKaboom

Comment: yeah, DataTrigger Binding is easier.I will ask a new quesiton.thank :) @Clemens